# How to use SIFT and SURF algorithm in Google colab with opencv4?

Tags: python, opencv, google-colaboratory, sift, surf

- My code on Google Colab

```
import cv2 as cv

image = cv.imread("/content/drive/My Drive/Image.bmp")
gray_image = cv.cvtColor(image,cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

sift = cv.xfeatures2d_SIFT.create()
keyPoints = sift.detect(image,None)

output = cv.drawKeypoints(image,keyPoints,None)

cv.imshow("FEATURES DETECTED",output)
cv.imshow("NORMAL",image)

cv.waitKey(0)
cv.destroyAllWindows()
```

- ERROR

*AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
 in ()
4 gray_image = cv.cvtColor(image,cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
5
----> 6 sift = cv.xfeatures2d_SIFT.create()
7 keyPoints = sift.detect(image,None)
8

- AttributeError: module 'cv2.cv2' has no attribute 'xfeatures2d_SIFT'

Comment: Check here: https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/07/16/where-did-sift-and-surf-go-in-opencv-3/

Comment: These algos are patented. ORB is not bad though and you might consider giving it a try.

Comment: He thanks I saw that link already that's not for Windows. About SURF and SIFT algorithm we can't use them in python contributing? Is there any other method I can use please suggest.

Answer (score 4):

the first thing to do is see the exact version you are using, all just running:

```
print (cv2 .__ version__)
```

if **version = 4.4.0** then `sift = cv2.SIFT_create ()`

if **version = 4.3.x** then `sift = cv2.xfeatures2d.SIFT_create ()`

if **Version = 4.2.x or 4.1.xu 4.0.x**, then SIFT will not work, it is not taken into consideration during the construction of the python package, the activation of the open-contrib module as well as the use of algorithms non free have not been activated.

on google colab you can install the opencv version you want by simply using a **pip** command preceded by an exclamation point **"!"** and specify the opencv version as follows:

```
!pip install opencv-contrib-python==4.4.0.44
```

**Note:**
As I write this, the last available version of openv in C ++ is version 4.5.0
, and the latest version of opencv python package is 4.4.0.44

Comment: Rashid Ladjouzi thanks this made my day.                                                                   
  !pip install opencv-contrib-python==4.4.0.44  this worked for me.Thanks

Comment: your welcome, you can check this for more explanation: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64525431/12848103