# Compute descriptor with Sift compute python

Tags: python, opencv, sift

I am trying to compute descriptors given a set of  `Keypoint`  that i have computed with `cv2.KeyPoint` !
But when i try to call  `sift.compute()`  like this, just to see if it works:

```
sift= cv2.SIFT()
sift.compute(img, Keypoint)
```

I get the following error that i can't manage to understand:  `<method 'compute' of 'cv2.Feature2D' objects> returned NULL without setting an error`

I am using Opencv 4.4

Comment: it's a redending question, you just have to search, there are plenty of posts on that https://stackoverflow.com/a/64525431/12848103

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at the [documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/4.4.0/da/df5/tutorial_py_sift_intro.html)

You should declare `SIFT` as:

```py
sift = cv.SIFT_create()
```

Therefore the correct code will be:

```py
sift = cv.SIFT_create()
kp, des = sift.detectAndCompute(gray,None)
```

**Update**

If you have already calculated the key-points (`kp`) then draw it on the current image:

```py
img=cv.drawKeypoints(gray,kp,img)
cv.imwrite('sift_keypoints.jpg',img)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the method that you like:
methode 1:

```
img = cv2.imread('../input/data-for-knn/data/train/airplane/0000.jpg')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)
sift = cv2.SIFT_create()
kp = sift.detect(gray,None)
desc = sift.compute(gray,kp)
```

methode 2:

```
des = sift.detectAndCompute(gray,None)
```